# JavaScript primitives: same memory location, new memory location, or engine-dependent?

Tags: javascript, memory, primitive, primitive-types

```
10    var x = 5;
11    x = 10;
```

Does the memory location of the variable `x` change in line 11 from line 10 OR does the JavaScript engine just overwrites the memory space originally allocated to `x` in line 10 and place the value `10` there? Is this specified, or engine-dependent?

Comment: Can you explain how this is going to affect your code? Otherwise, it's a fun question, but not about a specific problem, which is what's expected at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does everything on StackOverflow have to be affecting one's code directly to be considered legitimate? Really? I can't just ask a question that increases the depth of my knowledge of what's going on behind the scene?

Comment: Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JuanMendes when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Hopefully, this question will get closed anyway

Comment: @JuanMendes We can all relax now. I closed the question. Never thought a hair splitting difference between nuances of what is deemed a legitimate question could bring on a negative response like that from someone. You'd think I tried to kick a puppy.

Comment: This question seems clear and focused. I do not see how this is "too broad"... There is only one possible answer (new allocation or overwriting or engine-dependent) which would be fairly short (quote from the docs or the specs and explanations). I do not think this is too broad in any way and have edited from review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management), assigning values means reading and writing to memory that is already allocated.

When you assign a variable, memory is allocated. When you change its value, reading and writing is done on the same memory location.

Comment: That may be true of Mozilla's SpiderMonkey, but that doesn't mean it's not engine-dependent. (I can't imagine it is, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I could certainly imagine engine-dependent optimisations that change everything we thought to know about variables :-) It could easily be two processor registers filled with the different values, or no `5` being created at all (but a `10` right away).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @ ,what if I change x = 'a really long string' or some large number that take could more than the preallocated memory - wouldn't it be impossible to reuse the variable assigned memory ? something like let x = null, and the x = 999999999999999. or does it change the variable into a reference pointer to some other memory despite being a primitive data to primitive data change?